# How to get and change System password using servlet?

Tags: java

I have to get system(windows) username , system(windows) current password and change the current password with new password using SERVLET code.

Comment: There is no way of doing that.

Comment: What is your "system"?

Comment: any desktop install with window

Comment: I have to get the system(windows) password and change that password using servlet (java code)

Comment: that was not more info.  that was (almost not) restating what you have above.  Also, good luck.  Java is a VM; and I don't think there's any way you'll be allowed to do that, unless you choose to hack java (which happens a lot these days)

Comment: Is your JVM running under a user with administator rights?

Comment: Do you mean the user / password of your Client-Side or Serverside? Would you use a Operating System with a "getPasswordForUser(String username)" API?

Comment: Just a question: wouldn't this be a security hole is it was possible?

Comment: Are you trying to hack some stuff ?? - Thanks - TechIdiot

Answer (score 3):

Getting the current windows password is not possible. But if your JVM is running under a user account with admin rights, you can reset a users password by using the `ProcessBuilder` class and the windows `net user` command.

```
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("net", "user", "someUsername", "somePassword");
Process pro = pb.start();
```

To check the result of the command, read from it's Error Stream and Input Stream of the `Process` object returned by the `exec` method.

```
BufferedReader bre = null;
BufferedReader bri = null;
try{
    bre = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getErrorStream()));
    bri = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(pro.getInputStream()));
    pro.waitFor(); //wait for the command to finish
    String line;
    while((line = bre.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
    while((line = bri.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);
} finally {
    if(bre != null)
        bre.close();
    if(bri != null)
        bri.close();
}
```

Comment: [Don't use Runtime#exec](http://www.javaworld.com/jw-12-2000/jw-1229-traps.html?page=1), use [ProcessBuilder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html). Also, you don't read the process output right, see [basic I/O tutorial for character streams](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/charstreams.html). The way your doing it will probably leave the process output unread in the buffer.

Comment: Updated. Valid point on the BufferedReader, wrote it in a hurry and don't know what I was thinking. And thanks for the info on Runtime#exec.

Comment: np , glad to help. upovted.

Comment: @Arif Mohd, I see you posted several duplicates of this questions. If this answer is unsatisfactory, please comment as to why and maybe we can get you the answer you need.